# How to handle Pinch in & out in UWP apps

Tags: uwp, gesture

I have a `TextBlock` in my App. I want to handle `pinch in & out` on it to resize the font of that. when `ManipulationDelta` event fires I check `Scale` property, But most of times `Scale` is 1 even my fingers getting far from or getting nearer.
or it doesn't work as I expected.

can anybody show me an example how to find that pinch in or out happened?

Answer (score 0):

Put a scrollviewer around it. It has zooming via pinch out of the box.

Comment: no I can not use scrollviewer, I should handle it myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `ManipulationMode` on the `TextBlock` to `Scale`?

Also, I would suggest you put the manipulation on a `Grid` or `Border` container with `Transparent` background to capture the manipulation events. In the case of a `TextBlock` you could be running into hit testing issues that might cause the manipulation events not being fired.

```
<Grid ManipulationMode="Scale" ManipulationDelta="YourHandler">
   <TextBlock Text="YourTextBlock" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: as I said the event get fired and i don't have problem with it. I don't know why most of time it is 1 or how to find that pinch in happened?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there're some issues in your code, but I've made a simple code sample. It can achieve your target.

Please check the following code:

```xml
<Grid Background="Red" Height="200" ManipulationDelta="StackPanel_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationMode="Scale">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Verdana"
           FontSize="32"
           FontWeight="Bold"
           Foreground="SteelBlue"
           Text="Scaled Text" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="True">
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScaleTransform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    ScaleTransform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
}
```